# Podman push not verbose and VM out of sync

Tags: podman

Docker recently announced a Policy Pricing change and while I am waiting for the official position of the company I am working with I decided to migrate to podman. I know there are differences between Docker and podman.

On Mac using these commands I have an environment pretty similar to the previous one:

```
brew install podman
podman machine init
podman machine start
ln -s /usr/local/bin/podman /usr/local/bin/docker
```

The ln command is useful to still use docker command instead of podman. ln is better than alias because there are some command lines (i.e. ibmcloud) that require an executable for docker command and alias don't work.

then in the `.bash_profile` I added to avoid to specify `--format=docker` at every `docker build` command:

```
export BUILDAH_FORMAT=docker
```

Now I have two issues I don't know how to address:

1. `docker push` is not verbose, so I cannot see progress. For a large build, this is not a good user experience. However, this behavior is strange because `podman push` has a `--quiet` option and this let me think by default it should be verbose.
2. When I put my Mac on pause, the podman VM goes out of time sync. This is a problem when I run commands like:

```
apt-get update
```

when I build docker images because the build always gets this error:

```
E: Release file for http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 10h 44min 40s).
```

I know I can log in on podman VM with `podman machine ssh` command and install tools like `ntpupdate` but if I destroy the VM I need to do it every time. Another approach is to stop/start the podman machine. Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/11541  stop/start is workaround now

Answer (score 3):

Podman machines use chrony for time synchronization. By restarting it, the large drift will be accepted and the time set immediately. But that would only be a one-time fix. Usually, the large drift happens if the host (laptop/computer) went to sleep for a while. To fix it for good, allow chrony to make arbitrarily large jumps to set the time (see [makestep](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/doc/3.4/chrony.conf.html#makestep)).

```
podman machine ssh 'sudo sed --in-place="" -e "s/^makestep.*/makestep 1 -1/" /etc/chrony.conf && sudo systemctl restart chronyd'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the discussion of https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/11541

I noticed below solution works for me

```
$ podman machine ssh "sudo systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd.service"
```